# How do I drop duplicates in panda table?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm very new to coding, and want the code to count the frequency of the words, but I am stopped because I'm unsure of how to remove duplicates.

```
txt = " remember all those walls we built remember those times"
words = txt.split()
for word in words:
    print (word + " " + str(txt.count(word)))
import pandas as pd
my_table = pd.DataFrame()
for word in words:
    tempdf = pd.DataFrame ({"word" : [word], "frequency" : [txt.count(word)]})
    my_table = my_table.append(tempdf)
print(my_table)
```

Comment: please format your code and put it in code tags to make it easier to read

Comment: Aside from a brace at line 4, indentation are all messed up too.

Comment: use import pandas as pd

Comment: or pandas.DataFrame.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax error is due to a closing missing parentheses (`)`) for `print` on the line *prior to* `import pandas as pd`. This line should read:

```
print(word + " " + str(txt.count(word)))
```

As a general tip for syntax errors, first check the preceding line or previous function call for missing or extra parentheses.

Comment: True, aslo the variable assignment `my table` will fail because of the space.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
txt = " remember all those walls we built remember those times"

words = txt.split()

for word in words:

    print(word + " " + str(txt.count(word)))

import pandas as pd

mytable = pd.DataFrame()

for word in words:

    tempdf = pd.DataFrame ({"word" : [word], "frequency" : [txt.count(word)]})
    mytable = mytable.append(tempdf)

print(mytable)
```

**or better with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):**

```
import pandas as pd
txt = " remember all those walls we built remember those times"
words = txt.split()
for word in words:
    print(word + " " + str(txt.count(word)) )

my_table=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame ({"word" : [word], "frequency" : [txt.count(word)]}) for word in words])
print(mytable)
```

---

keep in mind that you could also `update` the dictionary and then create the dataframe at the end

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra closing bracket in line 4,
and also add import pandas as pd in line 5 because you are using pd instead of pandas

Comment: Hi Sanchit, thank you for the feedback, When I made those changes it worked! Just so I can learn from this experience for next time, what is the difference between writing pd and pandas?

Comment: When we do import pandas as pd, we create an alias for pandas which could be used in our code without using pandas keyword and we can use pd instead. It is generally used when we don't want to write whole name of the module that we are importing.